# Groupby + correlation between DataFrame and Series

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a DataFrame `a` and Series `b`.  I want to find conditional correlation of each column of `a` to `b`, conditional on the value of `b`.  Specifically, I'm using `pd.cut` to break up `b` into 5 groups.  But instead of a standard quantile, I'm using standard deviations of `b` above or below the mean.

```
np.random.seed(123)

a = (pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000,3))
     .add_prefix('col'))
b = pd.Series(np.random.randn(1000))

mu, sigma = b.mean(), b.std()
breakpoints = mu + np.array([-2., -1., 1., 2.]) * sigma
breakpoints = np.append(np.insert(breakpoints, 0, -np.inf), np.inf)
# There are now 6 breakpoints to create 5 groupings:
# array([       -inf, -1.91260048, -0.9230609 ,  1.05601827,  2.04555785,
#                inf])

labels = ['[-inf,-2]', '(-2,-1]', '(-1,1]', '(1,2]', '(2,inf]']
groups = pd.cut(b, bins=breakpoints, labels=labels)
```

All is good through here.  I'm hung up on the final line, using `.corrwith` with `.groupby`, which throws a `ValueError`:

```
a.groupby(groups).corrwith(b.groupby(groups))
```

Any ideas?  The result of `a.corrwith(b)` is a Series, so I'm thinking the result here should be a DataFrame with the groups/buckets as columns.  For example, one column would be:

```
print(a[b < breakpoints[1]].corrwith(b[b < breakpoints[1]]))
# Correlation conditional on that `b` is [-inf, -2 stdev]
col0    0.43708
col1   -0.08440
col2   -0.02923
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution that's functional but not pretty:

```
full = a.join(b.to_frame(name='_drop'))
corrs = (full.groupby(groups)
         .corr()
         .loc[(slice(None), a.columns), '_drop']
         .unstack()
         .T)

print(corrs)
      [-inf,-2]  (-2,-1]   (-1,1]    (1,2]  (2,inf]
col0    0.43708  0.06716  0.02437  0.01695  0.05384
col1   -0.08440  0.04208  0.05529 -0.07146  0.14766
col2   -0.02923 -0.19672  0.01519 -0.02290 -0.17101
```